# Word VB Macro to C# Windows form PostMessage

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, sendmessage

I'm trying to use PostMessage to send a character from a Word Macro button to a Windows Forms desktop application but I'm not receiving what I expect in the application. I create the doc using a template in C# and give it a custom property, the desktop application window handle (sVsHandle). Then send a Postessage like this to the handle:

```
Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Public Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100

Option Explicit
Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI

Sub Onload(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set myRibbon = ribbon
End Sub

'Callback for Button onAction
Sub HandleButtons(ByRef control As IRibbonControl)

    Dim sText As String
    Dim sWordHandle As String
    Dim sVsHandle As Long
    Dim sMessage As String

    ActiveDocument.Saved = True
    sVsHandle = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Handle")
    sWordHandle = ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("wordHandle")

    Call SendText(sVsHandle)
End Sub

Sub SendText(hWnd As Long)
    If hWnd = 0 Then MsgBox "no hWnd supplied": Exit Sub

    Dim zwParam As Long
    Dim zlParam As Long

    zlParam = &H1E0001
    zwParam = Asc("D")

    PostMessage hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, zwParam, zlParam

End Sub
```

I receive this in the windows forms application like so:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32",
                                        EntryPoint = "PostMessage",
                                        ExactSpelling = false,
                                        CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto,
                                        SetLastError = true)]

public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == 135)
        if (Convert.ToInt32(m.WParam) > 0)
        {
            StartUp.gclsViewDocs.EvaluateWordMessages(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(m.LParam));
        }
}
```

However lParam or wParam are always 0 and m.Msg always equals 135 despite expecting it to be &H100 (256).

I previously had this working with SendMessage but would like to change it to PostMessage. Can someone please explain where I'm going wrong, thanks.

Comment: 135 is WM_GetDlgCode.   When it was working with SendMessage was there a modal Dialog window showing?

Comment: no, I was using WM_SETTEXT and receiving 12 as expected

Comment: After [reading the documentation for WM_GetDlgCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425(v=vs.85).aspx), it occured to me that this message will be sent first and the receiver should respond. Since we can't do that, let the base do it. In my case, after receiving WM_GetDlgCode (and let the base handle it), I receive the WM_KEYDOWN.

Comment: And the lParam and wParam are OK: WINDOW MESSAGE WM_KEYDOWN, lParam / wParam / Msg: 1966081 / 68 / 256

Comment: Oh! We can send the response in the Result field of the msg. But we don't want to change the behaviour of how the Forms application receives input, therefore, just let the base handle it. For me, the key down message is received right after WM_GetDlgCode

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean by let the base handle it

Comment: To call base.WndProc.. I call this after checking the contents of the message. I don't know if this is related, but I can receive the WM_KEYDOWN right after the first message. I reproduced the case fully by the way, from a word macro to forms app.

Comment: You call that first.

Comment: So is it working now?